# Mapping REST endpoint and JSF2 view on same URI

Tags: spring, rest, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

The goal is to combine a REST based web interface with JSF2 GUI interface in such a way so that the URI path' to correspondig resource representations remain the same, i.e.:

- `sample.com/samepath/resource_rep.html`
  should map to JSF2 (get, post) - (note pretty URL)
- `sample.com/samepath/resource_rep.xml`
  should map to REST xml resource representation (get,post,put,delete)

Both identifiers, JSF2 `resource_rep.html` and REST `resource_rep.xml` would logically represent the same resource in different ways - once for human interaction (JSF2) and once for machine interaction (REST).

JSF2 + JAX-RS (Java EE 6) or JSF2 with SPRING (V3) are the two available choices for me.
Is such a thing possible and if yes, how can it be done?

Thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Map JSF on `*.html` and map JAX-RS on `*.xml`.

Please note that having `*.xml` extension is not really "RESTful".

Comment: Thanks for your comment - here the file endings only serve to make it clear that we have different resource representations on the same base-URI-path; of course the selection of the client accepted format must also be possible via format negotiation (i.e. via accept header)